# Extra 25% of site wide even to discount prices

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, discount, catalog-price-rules

How do I(on Magento 1.9) add a global price rule which is adding an additional 25% discount to all products, even the ones which already have a discount

Comment: Hi @David, what version of Magento is this question about? Please provide as much info as possible to help people answer your question.

Comment: Hello , Thank You for your comment , i have 1.9

Comment: I rephrased the question to be easier understandable, hope its ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a shopping cart rule. Have a read of http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html

Comment: Thank You . But i need it on catalog view .

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

Comment: There is no explanation how to add 25%  to 10% that i already have . The condition when you applying is to original price not to discounted

Comment: I think you would need two rules - one for the 25% for all products and another with an additional 10% for the already discounted products (and remove the Special Price in those product's Prices config). Set the 2nd rule with a higher priority [lower number] than the first and set it to allow further further rules to process. (I haven't tested this as I'm not in front of a magento installation right now)

Comment: Tested now and the two rule things works fine